# I'm trying to fetch a JSON file from an API

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I'm creating a new tab extension for chrome and I want to display the weather for the user. To do this I am using the geolocation API for the location and then openweather API for the weather data. The problem I have is when I use the fetch method it look for the file locally, this url :

chrome-extension://kgimldinjffdncnfpgflgjeaiafjdflp/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=56.692819099999994+&lon=12.8946167.

But I want it to look for the file on the internet, how do I solve this?

This is the code I am currently using.

```js
var OpenWeather;
if("geolocation" in navigator){
      // check if geolocation is supported/enabled on current browser
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position:Position){
        fetch("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"+&lon="+position.coords.longitude).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                OpenWeather=data;
                alert(OpenWeather);
            });
        });


      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **https** in API url like this:

```
 fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"+&lon="+position.coords.longitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is a Promise that returns a response.

```
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json=> {});
// or
fetch(url).then(function (res) {
   return res.json();
}).then(function (json) {});
```